# Views Configure contextual filter by user's country

Tags: commerce

Drupal 7, commerce kickstart2.

Need to create a view with ContentType ProductDisplay. ProductDisplay has field Product. A Product has multiple field of a Country type.

User object has a property Country filed by IP2Country Module. The view need to show only products with user’s country.

View: type=page, link= /products (no other arguments in url expected), added releation Product

Here what I tried

1. Created Contextual filter: "*Product: Country List (indexed)*". Had to add index to this field so it can be select in contextual filter
2. Configured default argument for the "*When the filter value is NOT in the URL*". By using "hook_views_plugins" created "*Current user's Country name*" argument type. It is working and providing correct argument value  - user’s country

Didn’t manage to make it work. Also, tried some other things and spent few hours browsing web for a possible solution. Didn't find any similar problems or solution. There’re many examples with taxonomy terms and url args.

As a plan B,  think to create view for every country and override main view, but don't like it

Is a better solution to the task possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem!

All I did was correct, except one thing; I choose wrong View type during creation.

wrong: selected Show "*Product display*"

working: choose Show "*Content*" of type "*Product display*"

Don't know the difference, but it's working